# Question about word embeddings in a specific language model - GPT-2

Tags: natural-language-processing

How were the [GPT-2](https://openai.com/blog/better-language-models/) token embeddings constructed?

The authors mention that they used Byte Pair Encoding to construct their vocabulary. But BPE is a compression algorithm that returns a list of subword tokens that would best compress the total vocabulary (and allow rare words to be encoded efficiently).

My question is: how was that list of strings turned into the vectors that they actually used for training the model? The papers they published on the [original GPT](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/openai-assets/research-covers/language-unsupervised/language_understanding_paper.pdf) and its [follow-up GPT-2](https://d4mucfpksywv.cloudfront.net/better-language-models/language_models_are_unsupervised_multitask_learners.pdf) don't seem to specify those details.